# RStudio vs. plain R editor - saving plot

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

The following code works in plain R editor (that comes with R) and does not work in RStudio

```
pdf('test.pdf')
plot(seq(1:10), seq(1:10))
dev.off()
```

When I run it in RStudio I get in Acrobat "There was an error opening this document. This file is already open or in use by another application"

I get the same error if I use:

```
pdf('test.pdf')
to_save<-plot(seq(1:10), seq(1:10))
print(to_save)
dev.off()
```

I have R version 3.3.3 and RStudio: Version 1.0.136 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc.
This is on Win 7.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: That means that a program outside of R is open and blocking your access to the pdf file. Do you have the file open in Acrobat Reader or something when you are trying to write to it? Are you attempting the view the PDF in RStudio?

Comment: Also, your `to_save<-plot(...)` doesn't make sense. You can't assign base graphics to variables.

Comment: @Gregor, it works with `grid.arrange`, so I thought to try it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine on my RStudio. In my experience, that message when opening the pdf appears if the connection to the file has not been closed. Do you get the message

```
null device
          1
```

when executing `dev.off()`?

Comment: Worked, I had to execute `dev.off()` multiple times

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with `ggplot2`, `ggsave` is a great option:

```
ggplot(data.frame(seq(1:10), seq(1:10)), 
       aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
       geom_point()
ggsave("test.pdf")
```